# RAILS: has_one association based on non PK column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations, models, has-one

I have the following tables:

```
users 
  [id | name | type]

types
  [id | title]
```

I need to setup a `has_one` association ('users'.type => 'types'.id). But, as I understand, when I write something like:

**user.rb**

```
has_one :type
```

it seems to create a relation between 'users'.id and 'types'.id. How do I specify exactly 'users'.type => 'types'.id has_one association?

Comment: It will be better if you change type column in users table to type_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

**user.rb**

```
belongs_to :type
```

**type.rb**

```
has_many :users, foreign_key: "type_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your type column of users table to type_id

user.rb

```
belongs_to :of_type, class_name: 'Type', foreign_key: 'type_id'
```

type.rb

```
has_many :users
```

Rails console try to do something like

```
u = User.last
u.of_type
```

Last line will give you type record

If you don't want to rename column then in user.rb, you can write it as

```
belongs_to :of_type, class_name: 'Type', foreign_key: 'type'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79650/discussion-on-answer-by-test-rails-has-one-association-based-on-non-pk-column).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    in your user.rb 

    class User
      has_one :type, class: 'Type', foreign_key: 'type'
    end 

    in your type.rb

    class Type
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

Comment: If type is stored in user table then how can these associations will work?

Comment: I think your storing id of types table in your 'type' column in users table. right?